# Open a Specific page of PDF document in viewer

Tags: terminal, pdf, localhost, viewer

I would like to be able to open a specific page of a PDF document through any desktop search or terminal.

Example of url

```
file://localhost/Users/masi/Dropbox/Cardiology/2493.full.pdf#page=11
```

which works in browser, but not in PDF viewers i.e. though Desktop searchers. 
It does not work neither in terminal where it opens the document at the top without specific page and without correct document.

How can you open a specific page of PDF document in PDF viewer?